# LOOCV Cross-validation: lmer model

Tags: cross-validation, mixed-models, loocv

Kindly request assistance with the R code for the Leave-one-out CV (LOOCV) for the lmer model with k fold being random factors in the model. I believe the 'Caret' package does only for the lm/glm but not the Linear Mixed model. I might be wrong.

Your assistance will be highly appreciated!